# Is it possible to have a visual studio solution with both c++ and python projects?

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, swig

I'm using SWIG to generate python wrappers for a C++ DLL application and then build a PyQt GUI using those wrappers.

Is it possible to make a unified solution with both these projects in Visual Studio so that I can simultaneously debug the python UI code as well as the C++ DLL code?

Thanks!

Comment: I recommend using the Visual Studio IDE only version and telling it how to compile Python code.